# Set layout height and weight

Tags: android, layout

I know mobile/tablet height and weight.there is some layout.I give height and weidth according to mobile/tablet  height and weight .Please help me .I created layout height and weight according to mobile height/weight .
Please help me

Comment: Its very unclear what you have and what you want, aside that its connected with height and weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the layout height and width in layout xml file

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TitleLayOut"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#999999">
 </LinearLayout
```

You can even mention the values like "240px" for android:layout_width/android:layout_height

You can do this even in your code something like this

```
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.TitleLayOut);
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams    lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2);
```